# как сделать с помощью svg в background такие скошенные углы?

Tags: css3, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте как сделать с помощью svg в background такие скошенные углы ?

Comment: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle cx="168" cy="179" r="59" fill="white" />
</svg>` и то не `background`, а блоку в котором картинка дали `border-radius: 50%`

Answer (score 3):

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <polygon fill="#ffed00" points="0,0 0,100 50,100"/>
  <polygon fill="#ffed00" points="50,100 100,100 100,0"/>
</svg>
```